# How to upload files using AJAX in CodeIgniter 3.0?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form with textboxes and a file upload. When user click the button. The **textbox values** and **file upload name** is saved to the database and the files is uploaded to server. I've no experience doing it using AJAX. So, any help is greatly appreciated.

This is my form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" name="f_complaint" id="f_complaint">
     <input type="text" name="i_complaint" id="id_complaint" class="cl_complaint" />
     <input type="file" name="i_file" id="id_file" class="cl_file" />
     <input type="button" id="btn_upl" value="Save your complaint" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

This is my AJAX:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/inspinia/js/jquery-2.1.1.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js'); ?>"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url  = "<?php print base_url(); ?>complaint/saveadd";
    $('#btn_upl').on('click', function() {
        var formData = new FormData($(this).parent('form')[0]);
        //alert(url);

        $.ajax({
            url  : url,
            type     : 'POST',
            data     : formData,
            success : function (returndata) {
                alert(returndata);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my controller:

```
public function saveadd() {
    $config['upload_path']      = FCPATH."assets/uploads/";
    $config['max_size']         = '307200';  
    $config['file_name']            = "FILE - ".$_FILES['i_file']['name'];;
    $config['overwrite']        = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('i_file')) {
        //return false;
        redirect('app/');
    } else {
        redirect('complaint/add');
    }
}
```

What's wrong in the code? Even the alert is not fired. I do not want to use plugins

Comment: any errors in the console? that url doesnt look valid either as far as I understand it needs a full path

Comment: @SergioAlen no errors

Comment: I use the same url in other project (also featuring upload files but not use ajax) and it's working fine

Comment: try using `$("#f_complaint").on("submit", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); // rest of the code })` instead of on click, and check if the alert works

Comment: still no luck..

Comment: How does your controller know it's receiving an XMLHTTPREQUEST??

Comment: I never use AJAX to upload file. So, I have little experience on it.

Comment: change your redirect to return true or json return in controller and check

Comment: http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/05/sending-formdata-with-jquery-ajax/

Comment: @Shota can you solved your problem or not??

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong in the code? Even the alert is not fired.

Here is whats wrong.
1. Your alert is called on AJAX success, means once ajax call is successfully completed. But in your CI controller you are redirecting the ajax call hence your AJAX call never completes and never returns to "success function (returndata) :" block.

Now,to solve this just replace below code.

```
  //return false;
  redirect('app/'); replace with,
  echo "upload failed";exit;
```

AND

```
 redirect('complaint/add'); replace with
 echo "upload finished";exit;
```

This return values will be returned in "returndata" js variable.

Comment: Also, refer to the link @sintakonte shared in the comment to upload/pass image file using AJAX.

Comment: Debug in your controller. put an echo "text";exit; in first line in your "saveadd" function and check your AJAX request in browser's developer console.

Comment: Updated answer. Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this library: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html

And in wiki library is instruction for codeigniter: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki
CTRL+F -> Codeigniter

Always I use it and it works very well :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reference of upload file using ajax and codeigniter. I thing it is the best way to upload a file using ajax.

```
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax--net-21684
```